# Aren't a[][] and (*a)[] equivalent as function parameters?

Tags: c, arrays, gcc, language-lawyer, function-parameter

Function prototype

```
void foo(int n, int a[][]);
```

gives error about incomplete type while

```
void foo(int n, int (*a)[]);
```

compiles. As per the decay rule `int a[][]` is equivalent to `int (*a)[]` in this case and therefore `int (*a)[]` should also give an error about an incomplete type but GCC seems to accept it. Is there anything I am missing? 
This might be a GCC bug but I didn't find anything related to it.

Comment: The first function 'prototype' isn't a valid function prototype — you must specify the length of the second dimension.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler; I know. So do the second one. `int []` isn't a complete type but `int [n]` is.

Comment: I'm not sure why either would work. In both cases, the row size (the second [ ] for int a[ ][ ] or the only [ ] for int (*a)[ ] is not specified, so in either case the compiler would not know the location of a[1][0].

Comment: in `int (*a)[]` isn't `a` a pointer to an array of int, so not exactly equivalent?

Comment: @Olaf; Are you sure? Do you think I am asking about how to pass a 2D array to a function?

Comment: The two are equivalent only in the sense they are both invalid constructs.   Passing a 2D array to a function requires the second dimension to be specified, which your first declration does not do - therefore is invalid.    The so-called "decay" rule only applies to one dimension.    The second declares `a` as a pointer to an array, but the definition of the array type is incomplete since it has no dimension.   No idea why gcc accepts the second - possibly a compiler-specific extension.

Comment: @haccks: Looks like you do. But maybe you are missing information in your question what your actual problem is? I did not check the user asking or his reps actually. The question just looked like a beginner's problem.

Comment: @Peter; Yes! You got my question. That's what I am asking.

Comment: @Peter clang accepts it as well, but of course, you cannot index into this construct, so maybe it's just because a *pointer* to an incomplete type is allowed as a function parameter? Of course, there's no sensible way to *use* this parameter.

Comment: @FelixPalmen: Finally, a valid objection. Yes, that's strange indeed.

Comment: Looks like an incompatible extension to me, maybe something before `[*]` was introduced? See C11, 6.7.6.2p4

Comment: @FelixPalmen I don't think pointer to an incomplete type is accepted.

Comment: And I have a guess here: `int (*a)[]` is not an *incomplete type* given this definition: "*At various points within a translation unit an object type may be incomplete (lacking sufficient information to determine the size of objects of that type) or complete (having sufficient information).*" The size of the pointer is known... For arrays, there's a further constraint: "*The element type shall not be an incomplete or function type.*". Well, so far just guessing...

Comment: @haccks of course a pointer to an incomplete type is fine. `void` is an incomplete type, as are incomplete `struct`s.

Comment: I think I've seen this question before. From what I remember it boiled down to that a pointer to an incomplete type is always ok, unlike an array of incomplete type.

Comment: @Lundin I think the point is that a pointer to an incomplete type isn't an incomplete type itself ... but maybe I'm wrong here.

Comment: @FelixPalmen You can always have a pointer to an incomplete type. The type might get completed in a different translation unit etc.

Comment: `int a[][]` is not a valid C type. It's a meaningless string of characters. You cannot apply array decay rules to it. You need to start with a valid C type.

Comment: @Peter there is nothing in decay rules that deserves the "so-called" qualifier. Decay is a term employed by the C standard.

Comment: @n.m. is `int (*a)[]` a valid type?

Comment: Yes it is. This doesn't lend any validity to `int[][]`.

Comment: @n.m. the C standard calls it "adjustment".

Comment: @FelixPalmen I stand corrected. Must have confused it with the C++ standard.

Comment: I still don't see any reference to the standard allowing this declarator. Neither in the comments, nor in the answers. If any, it would have to be `int (*a)[*]` which is a complete type.

Comment: @Olaf are you doubting that the standard allows pointers to incomplete types? See e.g. an example in 6.2.7/5.

Comment: @Peter : No. A pointer to an array of unknown size is a perfectly legal construct in C. There's nothing illegal in `int (*x)[]` declaration, including in function parameter contexts.

Comment: @n.m.: Hmm, I was not aware of this, thanks! Actually that#s a good reason to use array notiation for declarators, not the (more explicit) pointer variant then. Would be good if the answers would elaborate on this using the standard, though.

Comment: This deserves [tag:language-lawyer]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, they are not equivalent as function parameters. They are not equivalent in exactly the same way as parameter declarations in `foo` and `bar`

```
struct S;
void foo(struct S* s); // OK
void bar(struct S a[]); // ERROR: incomplete type is not allowed
```

are not equivalent.

C does not allow incomplete types as array elements (see C 1999 6.7.5.2/1: "[...] The element type shall not be an incomplete or function type. [...]") and this restriction applies to array parameter declarations the same way as it applies to any other array declarations. Even though parameters of array type will be later implicitly *adjusted* to pointer type, C simply provides no special treatment for array declarations in function parameter lists. In other words, array parameter declarations are checked for validity *before* the aforementioned adjustment.

Your `int a[][]` is the same thing: an attempt to declare an array with elements of type `int []`, which is an incomplete type. Meanwhile, `int (*a)[]` is perfectly legal - there's nothing unusual about pointers to incomplete types.

As a side note, C++ "fixed" this issue, allowing arrays of incomplete type in parameter declarations. However, the original C++ still prohibits `int a[][]` parameters, `int (&a)[]` parameters and even `int (*a)[]` parameters. This was supposedly fixed/allowed later in C++17 (http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#393)

Comment: why this `void bar(int a[]); ` allowed then?

Comment: @haccks: because `int` is not an incomplete type.

Comment: @haccks: I'm not sure I understand the question. The problem with the above `struct S a[]` is that `struct S` is an incomplete type (i.e. array *element* type is incomplete). There's no such problem with `int a[]`, since `int` is a complete type.

Comment: @AnT int a[][] `int` is not an incomplete type.

Comment: @cheroky: `int a[][]` declares `a` as an array of elements of type `int []` . Since `int []` is an incomplete type, this declaration is invalid. The fact that `int` is not incomplete does not help here in any way.

Comment: @AnT; As per array to pointer conversion rule `int a[][]` should decay to `int (*a)[]`, isn't it?

Comment: @haccks: Well, the whole point of my answer is that C checks the correctness of array declaration *before* it performs transformation of array parameters to pointer parameters. And the check fails. For the very same reason `int a[-2]` in parameter declaration will also fail, even though array size "does not really matter" and that it "will decay to plain `int *` anyway". But the rules of the language are written that way. Array declaration shall be a valid array declaration even if it is used in parameter list and even though it will decay to pointer later.

Comment: @AnT; It would be great if you could add a reference from standard for the line: *and this restriction is extended to array parameter declarations*.

Comment: @haccks: More precisely, it is not "extended", but rather "not relaxed".  The restrictions are given in 6.7.5.2 and nowhere in the standard it says that parameter declarations are exempt from these restrictions.

Comment: I dont see how C99 6.7.5.2/1 is relevant. It is regarding what you are allowed to put as an expression between [ and ]. It says, correctly cited: "In addition to optional type qualifiers and the keyword static, **the [ and ] may delimit an expression** or *. If they delimit an expression (which specifies the size of an array), the expression shall have an integer type. If the expression is a constant expression, it shall have a value greater than zero. The element type shall not be an incomplete or function type."  None of this is concerning the type of the actual array.

Comment: Also please note that C11 uses different chapter numbers. This would be 6.7.6.1 in the current standard.

Comment: "C does not allow incomplete types as array elements". C does however allow incomplete types as part of a function declaration. C11 C11 6.7.6.3/12.

Comment: @Lundin: The relevant portion of the text of 6.7.5.2/1 (per C99 n numbering) is quoted in my answer and its relevance is obvious. "The element type shall not be an incomplete or function type." How is that not relevant? Meanwhile, I don't see how your "C does however allow incomplete types as part of a function declaration" is relevant. It is true, but it cannot make invalid array declaration into a valid one.

Comment: @AnT Because the whole paragraph speaks of the expression between [ and ]. Are you saying that they sneaked in a non-related sentence in the middle of the paragraph, then moved on to continuing describing what you may put between [ and ]? I read this as that the expression between [ ] may not have incomplete type. Which I suppose doesn't make much sense as it should be an integer and nothing else. If they sneaked in a non-related sentence there then the standard is very poorly written though.

Comment: @Lundin: Huh? That sentence is very explicit and perfectly clear: "**The element type** shall not be an incomplete or function type." There isn't a slightest doubt that they are talking about *array element type*, not about expression between `[]`. As you noted yourself, integer type cannot possibly be incomplete type (or function type)..

Comment: @AnT You are probably correct, though I find it very confusing that they sneaked in that sentence in the middle of an explanation about `[*]` `[static n]` and other such exotic features.

Comment: This answer states “C simply provides no special treatment for array declarations in function parameter lists,” but C 1999 6.7 7 says “in the case of function arguments (including in prototypes), it is the adjusted type (see 6.7.5.3) that is required to be complete.” C 2018 6.7 7 has the same text except the clause referred to is 6.7.6.3.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil: When I say "provides no special treatment" I only mean that basic validity requirements imposed on array parameter declarations are the same as for other array declarations: element type shall be complete, size (if any) shall be positive. You have to pass through these requirements *before* you get to any adjustments. Your quote is about "adjusted type", which for a *later* stage. Frankly, I don't see the relevance of what you quoted. You cannot "adjust" array parameter declarations before you establish them as *valid* array parameter declarations. That's the whole point.

Comment: @AnT: One **can** — it is not logically impossible — adjust array parameters before one establishes them as valid array parameter declarations. Given `int a[][]`, an array of an unknown number of arrays to an unknown number of `int`, one could adjust it to be a pointer to an array of an unknown number of `int`, and then decide whether that is a valid parameter. 6.7 7 clearly tells us that one rule for determining whether a parameter is valid—whether its type is complete—is **not** to be applied before adjustment; it is to be applied after adjustment.…

Comment: … Now, the rule it is telling us to be applied after adjustment is the rule about the parameter type being complete, not the rule about array elements being complete. But this answer misstates that C does not provide special treatment for array declarations in function parameter lists. You mean have **meant** there is no special treatment regarding only the rule about array elements, but your **text** does not say that. Given there is some dispute and that C does provide special treatment for at least one rule, these things ought to be clarified.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil: No, I strongly disagree. Type adjustments are applied to *array declarations* in parameter lists. In order to be an *array declaration* the declaration has to satisfy the requirements of 6.7.5.2. Something that "looks like" an array declaration (has `[]` in it and matches the general syntax) is not yet an "array declaration" until it passes all requirements of 6.7.5.2. It is 6.7.5.2 that makes an array declaration. Until a syntactic construct meets the rules of 6.7.5.2, no further rules specific to *array declarations* apply to that syntactic construct.

Comment: You cannot apply any array-specific adjustments to `int a[][]` until you demonstrate that this is indeed an *array declaration*. It surely looks like one  at the first sight (and even the grammar agrees), but this is definitely not enough. Until you demonstrate that `int a[][]` can pass through 6.7.5.2, the language will not recognize `int a[][]` as an array declaration. Until that moment array-specific parameter type adjustments cannot and will not apply to `int a[][]`. And the point is: `int a[][]` does not meet the requirements of 6.7.5.2. It is *not* an array declaration.

Comment: @AnT: You say you strongly disagree, and then your next sentence is “Type adjustments are applied to array declarations in parameter lists.” I did not write anything to the contrary of that sentence. So what are you disagreeing with? Note that I wrote you **can** —it is logically possible — to adjust array parameters before one establishes them as valid array parameter declarations. I did **not** write that such behavior conforms to the rules of C. I simply assert it is possible to write computer code that behaves in such a way. This point is one step in explaining why clarity is needed about…

Comment: … stating what rules apply and whether there are special rules for function parameters.

Comment: In any case, the statement “C simply provides no special treatment for array declarations in function parameter lists” is false. 6.7 7 provides for special treatment. It may not have been what you were thinking of or what you meant, but the text as written is false.

Answer (score 6):

An incomplete type is allowed in contexts where the size doesn't need to be known.

With this declaration:

```
int a[][]
```

It is invalid even as a function parameter because the size of one array dimension is needed to know how to perform pointer arithmetic on the second dimension.

This however is valid:

```
int (*a)[];
```

Because the size of the array doesn't need to be known in order to use a pointer to it.

Section 6.2.7 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) gives an example of a declaration like this:

> *5* EXAMPLE Given the following two file scope declarations:
>
> ```
> int f(int (*)(), double (*)[3]);
> int f(int (*)(char *), double (*)[]);
> ```
>
> The resulting composite type for the function is:
>
> ```
> int f(int (*)(char *), double (*)[3]);
> ```

This example shows a declaration of type `double (*)[3]` that is compatible with a declaration of type `double (*)[]`

You can't however directly use this like a 2D array because of the missing size.  Here are some examples to illustrate.  If you attempt to do this:

```
void foo(int n, int (*a)[])
{
    int i,j;
    for (i=0;i<n;i++) {
        for (j=0;j<n;j++) {
            printf("a[%d][%d]=%d\n",i,j,a[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

The compiler (as expected) tells you this:

```
error: invalid use of array with unspecified bounds
         printf("a[%d][%d]=%d\n",i,j,a[i][j]);
         ^
```

You can get around this by taking advantage of the fact that an array, even of indeterminate size, decays to a pointer in most contexts:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(int n, int (*a)[])
{
    int i,j;
    for (i=0;i<n;i++) {
        // dereference "a", type is int[], which decays to int *
        // now manually add "n" ints times the row
        int *b = *a + (n*i);
        for (j=0;j<n;j++) {
            printf("a[%d][%d]=%d\n",i,j,b[j]);
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int a[2][2] = { {4,5},{6,7} };
    foo(2,a);

    return 0;
}
```

This compiles clean with the following output:

```
a[0][0]=4
a[0][1]=5
a[1][0]=6
a[1][1]=7
```

Even outside of a function, the `int (*)[]` syntax can be used:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a[2][2] = { {4,5},{6,7} };
    int i,j,n=2;
    int (*aa)[];
    // "a" decays from int[2][2] to int (*)[2], assigned to int (*)[]
    aa = a;
    for (i=0;i<n;i++) {
        int *b = *aa + (n*i);
        for (j=0;j<n;j++) {
            printf("a[%d][%d]=%d\n",i,j,b[j]);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm not convinced that it's completely defined behaviour to pass a 2-dimensional `int[][]` as a 1-dimensional `int[]` - does the standard guarantee no padding is inserted?  I'm surprised GCC doesn't even warn about this, even with `-Wall -Wextra`

Comment: I used `gcc -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wwrite-strings -Wno-parentheses -Wpedantic -Warray-bounds` without complaint...

Comment: @TobySpeight: Padding is not the problem (otherwise `malloc` would not work for a nD array), but the effective type (aka strict aliasing) rule. Anyway, I don't see this is a valid declarator.

Comment: As it read from the standard the declarator is already illegal. gcc should indeed warn. The fact it warns about the equivalent array-style supports this. If you think different, references to the standard would be helpful.

Comment: @TobySpeight: padding is only allowed *within* types, never *between* elements of an array.  Otherwise array indexing and pointer arithmetic would not work.  So an array of arrays (`T[m][n]`) is always equivalent to an array `T[m*n]` that can be indexed with `i*n + j`.

Comment: You can get the length by int (*a)[ ];  int lgth = (a+1 - a) - 1;

Comment: @TobySpeight You cannot pass arrays to functions. `int(*)[]` is a pointer to the first element of the 2D array as is perfectly fine for the same reason as `int*` can be used as a pointer to the first element of a 1D array. The C standard definition of an array does not allow any padding; its memory must be contiguous.

Comment: As for if an array pointer to an incomplete array is compatible with an array pointer to an array of fixed size, I am not sure. 6.7.6.2/6: "For two array types to be compatible, both shall have compatible element types, and if both size specifiers are present, and are integer constant expressions, then both size specifiers shall have the same constant value. If the two array types are used in a context which requires them to be compatible, it is undefined behavior if the two size specifiers evaluate to unequal values."  It does not mention what happens if one array is incomplete.

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT**

Having read through all the relevant parts of the standard, C11 6.7.6.2 and 6.7.6.3, <strike>I believe this is a compiler bug/non-conformance.</strike> it apparently boils down to the text that the committee sneaked into the middle of a paragraph concerning array delimiters. 6.7.6.2/1 emphasis mine:

> In addition to optional type qualifiers and the keyword static, the [
>   and ] may delimit an expression or *. If they delimit an expression
>   (which specifies the size of an array), the expression shall have an
>   integer type. If the expression is a constant expression, it shall
>   have a value greater than zero. T**he element type shall not be an
>   incomplete or function type.** The optional type qualifiers and the
>   keyword static shall appear only in a declaration of a function
>   parameter with an array type, and then only in the outermost array
>   type derivation.

Now this is of course very poorly written, basically it says

> "peripheral feature of little interest, peripheral feature of little
>   interest, peripheral feature of little interest, **OUT OF THE BLUE HERE COMES SOME ARRAY ELEMENT TYPE SPECIFICATION NOT RELATED TO THE REST OF THIS PARAGRAPH**, peripheral feature of little interest, peripheral feature
>   of little interest,...."

So it is easy to misunderstand, fooled me.

Meaning that `int a[][]` is always incorrect no matter where it is declared, since an array cannot be an array of incomplete type.

However, my original answer below raises some valid concerns regarding whether array decay should be done before or after the compiler decides if the type is incomplete or not.

---

Given the specific case `void foo(int n, int a[][]);` only, this is a function *declaration*. It is not a definition.

C11 6.7.6.3/12

> If the function declarator is not part of a definition of that
>   function, parameters may have incomplete type

So first of all, parameters *are* allowed to have incomplete type in the function declaration. The standard is clear. Which is why code like this compiles just fine:

```
struct s; // incomplete type
void foo(int n, struct s a); // just fine, incomplete type is allowed in the declaration
```

Furthermore:

C11 6.7.6.3/4

> After adjustment, the parameters in a parameter type list in a function declarator that is part of a definition of that function shall not have incomplete type.

*After adjustment* is very important here.

Meaning that after adjusting `int a[][]` to `int (*a)[]`, the parameter shall not have incomplete type. It does not, it is *a pointer to incomplete type*, which is always allowed and perfectly fine.

The compiler is not allowed to first evaluate `int a[][]` as an incomplete array of incomplete arrays, and then later adjust it (if it found that the type was not incomplete). This would directly violate 6.7.6.3/4.

Comment: There might very well be parts elsewhere in the standard that makes the `int a[][]` declaration illegal, but I can't find anything about it in the declaration chapter. GCC is not the only compiler giving an error for this format.

Comment: Now your answer completely contradicts the accepted answer, though your answer is more convincing. At first this looked a bug to me and I was thinking in a same way.

Comment: @haccks See comments to the answer by AnT. After reading through this again, the text he quoted is probably the relevant part after all. Meaning that it is all as simple as "an array can not have elements of incomplete type". No matter where that array happens to be declared, inside a parameter list or elsewhere. I'll leave this answer up though, since the quoted parts are still highly relevant to the topic.